# Best way to display the rounded value of a number in a struct

Tags: swift, performance, struct

I am looking for the most efficient way to do this:

In my app there is a struct called Color(). It consists of 3 Floats (one for each color in the RGB format). To display the current red, green or blue value to the user it needs to be rounded. To be saved and used otherwise in my app, it needs to remain the same. 
I have simply added three computed properties to my Color() struct. This however, seems like inefficient programming to me. Is there a better way?

```
struct Color {
var red, green, blue: Float
var roundedRed: Float {
    return round(red * 10) / 10
}
var roundedGreen: Float {
    return round(green * 10) / 10
}
var roundedBlue: Float {
    return round(blue * 10) / 10
}
init(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float) {
    self.red = red
    self.green = green
    self.blue = blue
}
}
```

I know this won't matter for processing efficiency. I am simply trying to learn good code ettiquette.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the struct to hold the unrounded numbers and write an extension to Float to round as you need.

E.g.

```
struct Color {

    var red, green, blue: Float

    init(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
    }

}

extension Float {

    var rounded: Float {
        get{
            return round(self*10)/10
        }
    }

}
```

Then to get the rounded value you would just use

```
someColor.red.rounded
```

And if you only want to retrieve the value as a string, as dfri rightly picked is your intended use for this, you could add another computed variable to the extension, maybe called displayString, like so

```
extension Float {

    private var rounded: Float {
        get{
            return round(self*10)/10
        }
    }

    var displayString: String {
        get {
            return "\(self.rounded)"
        }
    }

}
```

To be used like this

```
someColor.red.displayString
```

(I made rounded private because in this implementation you wouldn't need it other than for the purpose of retrieving the displayString)

Comment: No problem :) nah with this design it would just be someColor.red (the components get rounded when the struct is initialised)

Comment: And if I want to have both the unrounded an rounded value available

Comment: I'll update my answer to include how I would do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use formatted `String` properties to represent the RGB values to the user

Instead on focusing that you want *"rounded values to display for the user"*, re-phrase this into the realization that you want a `String` representation of your `red`, `green` and `blue` `Float` values that you'd like to use for presenting the values in a formatted fashion to your user.

***Using stored `String` properties and property observers***

You could e.g. use three stored `String` properties that use a property observer (`willSet`) to trail the values in the `Float` properties:

```
struct Color {
    private static func toString(num: Float) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.02f", num)
    }

    var red:   Float { willSet { strRed   = Color.toString(num: newValue) } }
    var green: Float { willSet { strGreen = Color.toString(num: newValue) } }
    var blue:  Float { willSet { strBlue  = Color.toString(num: newValue) } }

    var strRed: String
    var strGreen: String
    var strBlue: String

    init(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        strRed = Color.toString(num: red)
        strGreen = Color.toString(num: green)
        strBlue = Color.toString(num: blue)
    }
}

// Float values used in application
let color = Color(red: 0.111, green: 0.2099, blue: 0.235)

// String representation of these used to present
// the values to the user
print(color.strRed, color.strGreen, color.strBlue) // 0.11 0.21 0.23
```

***Using computed `String` properties***

Depending on the application, a more sensible approach might to let the `String` properties be computed properties, computing them on call.

```
struct Color {
    private static func toString(num: Float) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.02f", num)
    }

    var red: Float
    var green: Float
    var blue: Float

    var strRed: String   { return Color.toString(num: red) }
    var strGreen: String { return Color.toString(num: green) }
    var strBlue: String  { return Color.toString(num: blue) }

    init(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
    }
}

let color = Color(red: 0.111, green: 0.2099, blue: 0.235)

print(color.strRed, color.strGreen, color.strBlue) // 0.11 0.21 0.23
```